# automating a task with ProcessBuilder - how to login?

Tags: java, automation, processbuilder

We have a terminal at work that users login and run some commands. This 'terminal' is an old IBM legacy system from the stone age that you can send a command and get replies. My objective is to automate some process with 'ProcessBuilder'.

I read about this feature and realized that this can be a key to solve a lot of our work. In a way, I'm thinking about a Java application that will automate all the work that currently users are doing on a daily basis. Instead of them punching the keys millions of times, the system will do that for them!

Problem is that I'm not sure how ProcessBuilder can do it? How will it login? wait for reply? how can I instruct go to menu 1 choose item 5 and input the message 'ABC' if the replay is 123 then type XYZ etc...?

Thanks!

Ps - if there's a different programming language that can do that - bring it on.

Comment: Does terminal support JVM ?

Comment: @Makky I'm not sure. how should I check it. Thanks!

Comment: This is what you have to find otu first.I don't know how to check...could you post example commands you've been sending to terminal?

Comment: it is called SNA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Systems_Network_Architecture

Comment: This is only possible with processbuilder if the terminal application runs from the command line, as you can then communicate with it via input/output streams. If it is a 'green screen' type app that opens in another window you probably won't be able to script it from java.